# Application not appearing on IIS after running setup

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, installation, iis-8

I have created a web setup in visual studio 2013. When I install it, only the bin folder is created in IIS, hence I cannot browse my website. Help please.
I have added the Primary Output in the Web Application folder in my setup.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is too confusing. Are you uploading your files on to the web server? Or are you trying to setup your visual studio for debugging, test, editing and coding purposes?

If you are trying to run Visual Studio locally, IIS is setup for you automatically.

If you are trying to setup files to a webserver, try to talk to the live support. Sometimes, we, users, dont have full control or lack of knowledge debugging it on the dedicated server.

Other thing to consider is reinstalling your visual studio carefully.